# Spring MVC Mockito Test returning 406 error instead of 200

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

So I am working with a working UI, and using a DB2 database. I am trying to run unit testing on the controller/service/dao layers and I am using mockito and junit to test. Here are the pieces of each layer:

`Measures.java`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/measures"})
public class Measures {

    @Resource
    private CheckUpService checkUpService;
    
    public void setCheckUpService(CheckUpService checkUp) {
        this.checkUpService = checkUpService;
    }    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/eligibility/{userId}/{effDate}/{stageInd}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Model> findEligibility(@PathVariable int userId, @PathVariable String effDate, @PathVariable String stageInd) throws Exception
    {
        List<Model> result = new ArrayList<Model>();

        if (stageInd.equals("stage"))
        {
            result = checkUpService.findEligibilityStage(userId, effDate);
        }

        if (stageInd.equals("prod"))
        {
            result = checkUpService.findEligibility(userId, effDate);
        }

        return result;
    }
...
}
```

`CheckUpService.java`

```
public class CheckUpService {

    @Resource
    EligibilityDao eligDao;

    public List<Model> findEligibility(int userId, String effDate) throws Exception
        {
             return eligDao.findEligibility(userId, effDate, db_table);
        }
}
```

`EligibilityDao.class`

```
public class EligibilityDao {

    public List<Model> findEligibility(int userId, String effDate, String table) throws Exception
        {
            // uses some long sql statement to get some information db2 database and 
            // jdbctemplate helps return that into a list.
        }
}
```

Here is the controller test that I am trying to do, I've spent about 10 hours on this and I really can't figure out why it's giving me a 406 error instead of 200.

`ControllerTest.java`

```
@EnableWebMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private Measures measures;
    
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    private List<Model> findEligibility() {
        
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Model test_model = new Model();
        
        test_model.setUserId(99);
        test_model.setCreateID("testUser");
        test_model.setEffDate("2020-07-30");
        
        list.add(test_model);
        
        return list;
    }
    
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test_find() throws Exception {
        
        CheckUpService checkUpService = mock(CheckUpService.class);
        
        when(checkUpService.findEligibility(99, "2020-07-30")).thenReturn(findEligibility());
        
        measures.setCheckUpService(checkUpService);
        
        String URI = "/measures/eligibility/99/2020-07-30/prod";
        
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URI).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        
        MvcResult handle = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

//      MvcResult handle = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(handle)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
        
//      assertThat(result.getResponse().getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(findEligibility()); 

    }
    
    
    
}
```

The MvcResult result is what is throwing the "StatusExpected <200> but was <406>" error in junit and i'm going mad on why it is. Another issue is that, if you can see, I commented out the handle with the .andExpect(status().isOk()) and that one was also throwing the same issue. Is it something i'm setting up wrong with the test or something?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue. However, I got this working.

So, no big changes to the `Controller`, but I removed the field injection in favor of constructor injection.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/measures")
public class Measures {

    private final CheckUpService checkUpService;

    public Measures(CheckUpService checkUpService) {
        this.checkUpService = checkUpService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/eligibility/{userId}/{effDate}/{stageInd}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Model> findEligibility(@PathVariable int userId, @PathVariable String effDate, @PathVariable String stageInd) throws Exception {
        List<Model> result = new ArrayList<>();

        if (stageInd.equals("stage")) {
            result = checkUpService.findEligibility(userId, effDate);
        }

        if (stageInd.equals("prod")) {
            result = checkUpService.findEligibility(userId, effDate);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The same for the service class.

```java
@Service
public class CheckUpService {

    private final EligibilityDao dao;

    public CheckUpService(EligibilityDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public List<Model> findEligibility(int userId, String effDate) throws Exception {
        return dao.findEligibility(userId, effDate, "demo value");
    }
}
```

and here's the test. Instead of initializing the MockMvc and injecting the web context, I inject MockMvc. Also, using `@MockBean`, you can inject mocks. So, I removed the mock creation from the test method to the initialization part.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MeasuresTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CheckUpService service;

    @Test
    public void test_find() throws Exception {
        Model model = new Model(99, "2020-08-02", "2020-07-30");
        when(service.findEligibility(99, "2020-07-30"))
                .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(model));
        String URI = "/measures/eligibility/99/2020-07-30/prod";

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URI)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        final MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        final String json = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        final List<Model> models = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<>() {
        });

        Assert.assertEquals(1, models.size());
        Assert.assertEquals(model, models.get(0));
    }
}
```

In the post, I could not find any reason why you used `asyncDispatch`, so I just did not use it.

Comment: When i try this i'm getting a NPE on "when(service.findEligibility(99, "2020-07-30")).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(model));"

When I debugged it, i saw that CheckUpService is null for some reason?

Comment: Does it have `@Service` annotation on top?

Comment: Yes, it has the @Service at the top

Comment: What version of Mockito, Spring boot, and Junit are you using?

Comment: I think spring boot is 3.8, Mockito is 4.10, junit is 4

Comment: I have no idea, tbh. Probably, something is not hooked up correctly.

Comment: i actually didnt add the SpringRunner.class, but it says the class isn't defined.

Comment: It is imported from `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner`, part of `spring-boot-starter-test`

Comment: i have to import that dependency to my POM.xml right

Comment: yes, you probably already have parent pom in your pom which is spring-boot. So, just adding this without a version works fine `<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId></dependency>`

Comment: Actually in this pom (which was here before me), there is no parent spring-boot. i think i was facing this similar issue when a tried using springrunner a couple weeks ago, where when i added the parent, it was breaking the whole pom

Comment: Then just add the one I mentioned and match the version with the current Spring Boot version of yours.

Comment: oh wait, there is already one in the pom, but its version is 2.3.Release

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219065/discussion-between-mensur-qulami-and-ihaveaquestion).